# Передача аргумента из url в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Пишу свой первый учебный проект на Django и не могу понять вот такую штуку.

Вот есть у меня 2 view - вывод постов на главной странице и вывод постов в категории.

Главная работает примерно так:

```
class MainPostList(View):
    def get(self, request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context={'posts': posts})
```

А категория примерно вот так:

```
class CategoryPostList(View):
    def get(self, request, category):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(category__alias=category)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context={'posts': posts})
```

category - это именованный аргумент, который магическим (не очень понятным мне) образом передается из urls.py, вот из этой строчки:

```
path('<category>/', CategoryPostList.as_view(), name='category_view_path')
```

Собственно, кроме того, что во втором случае в класс передается переменная category, разницы в работе нет. Поэтому я хочу написать mixin. Но я не понимаю как с этим category поступать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать в данном случае.

Comment: Не понял, что именно вы хотите. Зачем mixin?

Comment: Ну на самом деле в каждой вьюшке есть еще пагинация и это малость громоздко. А работает все, что в первом, что во-втором случае одинаково. Я хотел написать еще один класс, который бы все это делал и просто передавать в него список постов. В первом случае все посты, а во втором - фильруемые переменной category. Но я не понимаю как эту переменную передавать в этот общий класс.

Comment: Можно просто сделать функцию, которая всё это делает, и передавать в неё список постов :) (я вообще ненавижу class-based views)

Comment: Если хочется одну вьюху на два урла, можно просто недостающим параметрам прописать значение по умолчанию `def get(self, request, category=None):` и дальше в зависимости от того, None оно или не None, делать что там надо

Comment: Ну, допустим. А как потом внутри функции это значение по-умолчанию поменять? Чтобы category стало равно category? Сорян, если вопрос тупой, просто реально не понимаю

Comment: Если джанга укажет аргумент `category` при вызове вьюхи (а она его укажет), то значение по умолчанию использоваться не будет. Почитайте в учебниках по питону про аргументы функций

Comment: Ок, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Это не совсем то, что я хотел, но действительно работает одна вьюха на 2 урла. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Почему вы не используете готовые вьюхи? Зачем делать свой велосипед, если зачастую уже написанный код куда продуманее(и протестирован сообществом, что не мало важно), чем свое изобретение.

Ваш код можно записать так:

```
from django.views import generic

class PostListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'  # вьюха сама сгенерирует респонс с этим шаблоном

    def get_queryset(self):                                      # переопределяем получение объектов
        category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)             # получаем аргумент из ссылки
        if category is not None:                                 # если аргумент существует
            return Post.objects.filter(category__alias=category) # фильтруем по нему посты
        return Post.objects.all()                                # в другом случае - возвращаем все посты
```

Паттерны в `urls.py` должны выглядеть так:

```
path('', PostListView.as_view()),             
path('<category>/', PostListView.as_view()), #  ссылаемся на одну и ту же вьюху, в ней обрабатываем входящий аргумент(либо его отсутствие)
```

В шаблоне список объектов будет доступен через переменную `object_list`(работает во всех случаях) или `<model>_list`. Название зависит от названия модели, с которой вьюха получает queryset. В нашем случае можно будет обратиться через `post_list`.

Но это все тоже колхоз, который надо будет оттестить еще миллионы раз, чтобы все отрабатывало как часики. Например, что будет, если введут ID категории, которая не существует? То-есть нужна валидация, а это уже придется писать отдельно от вьюхи(и скорее всего что-то динамическое, не зацикленное на конкретно этом случае).

В случае какой-либо фильтрации чаще всего используют готовый модуль [django_filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter), там уже все предусмотрено(начиная с определения полей, по которым фильтруют, заканчивая вьюхой, наследуя которую можно быстро собрать нужный функционал). Однако сам модуль достаточно сложно будет начать использовать новичку, но все же рекомендую ознакомиться с его возможностями.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Некоторые моменты прояснились. Про готовые вьюхи я просто что-то не в курсе был. Поковыряюсь поподробнее по этому поводу. Ну а по поводу несуществующих id и так далее - в принципе в моей вьюхе есть валидация, которая дает 404 ошибку, вроде это не так сложно.